# Execute a custom command to close a running process before installation in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

My Setup.exe created by Inno Setup detects that one of the executable in my installation directly is currently running when i try and install an update.

I select "Automatically close the applications" and press *Next*. It seems Inno Setup does something to close this application, but it doesn't close it properly.

The system tray icon disappears but the process remains running.

I've no idea how Inno Setup attempts to close this application, but its not working whatever it's doing.

The application has a parameter `/exitall`, which closes all instances of this application including itself.

Is there any way to execute a command line command when the Setup.exe is run before Inno Setup detects the running applications?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes i have a clean way to shutdown the application. I just need to know how to execute my custom command before the installer gets to the point of trying to shut it down itself.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) to execute your "kill" command:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  AppPath: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    Log('Installing...');
    AppPath := ExpandConstant('{app}\MyProg.exe');
    if not FileExists(AppPath) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Application %s was not installed yet.', [AppPath]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Log(Format('Application %s is installed, running cleanup procedure...', [AppPath]));
      if not Exec(AppPath, '/exitall', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated,
                  ResultCode) then
      begin
        Log('Failed to run cleanup procedure.');
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

Though a standard way is to use `AppMutex` directive to prevent the installer from proceeding before a user closes the application.